# Unable to execute Airflow KubernetesExecutor

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Following the project from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/kubernetesexecutor-for-airflow-e2155e0f909c), I am trying to integrate airflow kubernetes executor using NFS server as backed storage PV. I've a PV `airflow-pv` which is linked with NFS server. Airflow webserver and scheduler are using a PVC `airflow-pvc` which is bound with `airflow-pv`. I've placed my dag files in NFS server `/var/nfs/airflow/development/<dags/logs>`. I can see newly added DAGS in webserver UI aswell. However when I execute a DAG from UI, the scheduler fires a new POD for that tasks BUT the new worker pod fails to run saying

`Unable to mount volumes for pod "tutorialprintdate-3e1a4443363e4c9f81fd63438cdb9873_development(976b1e64-b46d-11e9-92af-025000000001)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "development"/"tutorialprintdate-3e1a4443363e4c9f81fd63438cdb9873". list of unmounted volumes=[airflow-dags]. list of unattached volumes=[airflow-dags airflow-logs airflow-config default-token-hjwth]`

here is my webserver and scheduler deployment files;

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: airflow-webserver-svc
  namespace: development
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: web
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
  selector:
    app: airflow-webserver-app
    namespace: development

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: airflow-webserver-dep
  namespace: development
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: airflow-webserver-app
      namespace: development
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: airflow-webserver-app
        namespace: development
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: airflow-webserver-app
        image: airflow:externalConfigs
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        args: ["-webserver"]
        env:
        - name: AIRFLOW_KUBE_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: airflow-secrets
              key: AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: airflow-secrets
              key: MYSQL_PASSWORD
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: airflow-secrets
              key: MYSQL_PASSWORD
        - name: DB_HOST
          value: mysql-svc.development.svc.cluster.local
        - name: DB_PORT
          value: "3306"
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: airflow
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          value: airflow
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          value: airflow
        - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR
          value: "KubernetesExecutor"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: airflow-config
          mountPath: /usr/local/airflow/airflow.cfg
          subPath: airflow.cfg
        - name: airflow-files
          mountPath: /usr/local/airflow/dags
          subPath: airflow/development/dags
        - name: airflow-files
          mountPath: /usr/local/airflow/plugins
          subPath: airflow/development/plugins
        - name: airflow-files
          mountPath: /usr/local/airflow/logs
          subPath: airflow/development/logs
        - name: airflow-files
          mountPath: /usr/local/airflow/temp
          subPath: airflow/development/temp
      volumes:
        - name: airflow-files
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: airflow-pvc
        - name: airflow-config
          configMap:
            name: airflow-config
```

The scheduler yaml file is exactly the same except the container args is `args: ["-scheduler"]`. Here is my airflow.cfg file,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "airflow-config"
  namespace: development
data:
  airflow.cfg: |
    [core]
    airflow_home = /usr/local/airflow
    dags_folder = /usr/local/airflow/dags
    base_log_folder = /usr/local/airflow/logs
    executor = KubernetesExecutor
    plugins_folder = /usr/local/airflow/plugins

    load_examples = false

    [scheduler]
    child_process_log_directory = /usr/local/airflow/logs/scheduler

    [webserver]
    rbac = false

    [kubernetes]
    airflow_configmap =
    worker_container_repository = airflow
    worker_container_tag = externalConfigs
    worker_container_image_pull_policy = IfNotPresent
    delete_worker_pods = true
    dags_volume_claim = airflow-pvc
    dags_volume_subpath =
    logs_volume_claim = airflow-pvc
    logs_volume_subpath =

    env_from_configmap_ref = airflow-config
    env_from_secret_ref = airflow-secrets

    in_cluster = true
    namespace = development

    [kubernetes_node_selectors]
    # the key-value pairs to be given to worker pods.
    # the worker pods will be scheduled to the nodes of the specified key-value pairs.
    # should be supplied in the format: key = value

    [kubernetes_environment_variables]
    //the below configs gets overwritten by above [kubernetes] configs
    AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DAGS_VOLUME_CLAIM = airflow-pvc
    AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DAGS_VOLUME_SUBPATH = var/nfs/airflow/development/dags
    AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__LOGS_VOLUME_CLAIM = airflow-pvc
    AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__LOGS_VOLUME_SUBPATH = var/nfs/airflow/development/logs

    [kubernetes_secrets]
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN = airflow-secrets=AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN
    AIRFLOW_HOME = airflow-secrets=AIRFLOW_HOME

    [cli]
    api_client = airflow.api.client.json_client
    endpoint_url = https://airflow.crunchanalytics.cloud

    [api]
    auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default

    [admin]
    # ui to hide sensitive variable fields when set to true
    hide_sensitive_variable_fields = true
```

After firing a manual task, the logs of the Scheduler tells me that KubernetesExecutorConfig() executed with all values as None. Seems like it didn't picked up the configs ? I've tried almost everything I know of, but cannot manage to make it work. Could someone tell me waht am I missing ?

```
[2019-08-01 14:44:22,944] {jobs.py:1341} INFO - Sending ('kubernetes_sample', 'run_this_first', datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 1, 13, 45, 51, 874679, tzinfo=<Timezone [UTC]>), 1) to executor with priority 3 and queue default
[2019-08-01 14:44:22,944] {base_executor.py:56} INFO - Adding to queue: airflow run kubernetes_sample run_this_first 2019-08-01T13:45:51.874679+00:00 --local -sd /usr/local/airflow/dags/airflow/development/dags/k8s_dag.py
[2019-08-01 14:44:22,948] {kubernetes_executor.py:629} INFO - Add task ('kubernetes_sample', 'run_this_first', datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 1, 13, 45, 51, 874679, tzinfo=<Timezone [UTC]>), 1) with command airflow run kubernetes_sample run_this_first 2019-08-01T13:45:51.874679+00:00 --local -sd /usr/local/airflow/dags/airflow/development/dags/k8s_dag.py with executor_config {}
[2019-08-01 14:44:22,949] {kubernetes_executor.py:379} INFO - Kubernetes job is (('kubernetes_sample', 'run_this_first', datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 1, 13, 45, 51, 874679, tzinfo=<Timezone [UTC]>), 1), 'airflow run kubernetes_sample run_this_first 2019-08-01T13:45:51.874679+00:00 --local -sd /usr/local/airflow/dags/airflow/development/dags/k8s_dag.py', KubernetesExecutorConfig(image=None, image_pull_policy=None, request_memory=None, request_cpu=None, limit_memory=None, limit_cpu=None, gcp_service_account_key=None, node_selectors=None, affinity=None, annotations={}, volumes=[], volume_mounts=[], tolerations=None))
[2019-08-01 14:44:23,042] {kubernetes_executor.py:292} INFO - Event: kubernetessamplerunthisfirst-7fe05ddb34aa4cb9a5604e420d5b60a3 had an event of type ADDED
[2019-08-01 14:44:23,046] {kubernetes_executor.py:324} INFO - Event: kubernetessamplerunthisfirst-7fe05ddb34aa4cb9a5604e420d5b60a3 Pending
[2019-08-01 14:44:23,049] {kubernetes_executor.py:292} INFO - Event: kubernetessamplerunthisfirst-7fe05ddb34aa4cb9a5604e420d5b60a3 had an event of type MODIFIED
[2019-08-01 14:44:23,049] {kubernetes_executor.py:324} INFO - Event: kubernetessamplerunthisfirst-7fe05ddb34aa4cb9a5604e420d5b60a3 Pending
```

for reference, here is my PV and PVC;

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: airflow-pv
  labels:
    mode: local
    environment: development
spec:
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: airflow-pv
  capacity:
    storage: 4Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 10.105.225.217
    path: "/"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: airflow-pvc
  namespace: development
spec:
  storageClassName: airflow-pv
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      mode: local
      environment: development
```

Using Airflow version: **1.10.3**

Comment: Have you found something in Kubernetes logs,  like 'Exceptions'?

Comment: Kubernetes log... you mean the node logs ? where can I see them ?

Comment: Please run thic command: `kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system` and see that you had any restarts? Do you use minikube?

Comment: For some reason, airflow is unable to let me mount same volume for dags and logs. Things work fine if I create separate PV and PVC each for dags and logs, both pointing towards single NFS server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since no answer yet, I'll share my findings so far. In my airflow.conf under `kubernetes` section, we are to pass the following values

```
dags_volume_claim = airflow-pvc
dags_volume_subpath = airflow/development/dags
logs_volume_claim = airflow-pvc
logs_volume_subpath = airflow/development/logs
```

the way how scheduler creates a new pod from the above configs is as follows (only mentioning the volumes and volumeMounts);

```
"volumes": [
  {
    "name": "airflow-dags",
    "persistentVolumeClaim": {
      "claimName": "airflow-pvc"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "airflow-logs",
    "persistentVolumeClaim": {
      "claimName": "airflow-pvc"
    }
  }],
"containers": [
    { ...
  "volumeMounts": [
      {
        "name": "airflow-dags",
        "readOnly": true,
        "mountPath": "/usr/local/airflow/dags",
        "subPath": "airflow/development/dags"
      },
      {
        "name": "airflow-logs",
        "mountPath": "/usr/local/airflow/logs",
        "subPath": "airflow/development/logs"
      }]
...}]
```

K8s DOESN'T likes multiple volumes pointing to same pvc (airflow-pvc). To fix this, I'd to create two PVC (and PV) for dags and logs `dags_volume_claim = airflow-dags-pvc` and `logs_volume_claim = airflow-log-pvc` which works fine.

I don't kow if this has already been addressed in newer version of airflow (I am using 1.10.3). The airflow scheduler should handle this case when ppl using same PVC then create a pod with single volume and 2 volumeMounts referring to that Volume e.g.

```
"volumes": [
  {
    "name": "airflow-dags-logs",    <--just an example name
    "persistentVolumeClaim": {
      "claimName": "airflow-pvc"
    }
  }
"containers": [
    { ...
  "volumeMounts": [
      {
        "name": "airflow-dags-logs",
        "readOnly": true,
        "mountPath": "/usr/local/airflow/dags",
        "subPath": "airflow/development/dags"     <--taken from configs
      },
      {
        "name": "airflow-dags-logs",
        "mountPath": "/usr/local/airflow/logs",
        "subPath": "airflow/development/logs"     <--taken from configs
      }]
...}]
```

I deployed a pod with above configurations and it works!

Comment: how are the DAGs files copied to the the PV mounthPath/subPath? Do you have a separate CI/CD job to download the DAG code and copy it those PV?

Comment: Initially I was doing the same as you said. But later my environment picks up dags from image. So now, pipelines create new airflow image (with new/updated dags) and I point airflow-configs.yaml dags_folder to specified location under that image. In my case `/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/my_dags`.

Comment: @AnumSheraz I am trying to configure  `KuberenetesExecutor` for Airlfow and have similar config as you but I am getting `Service token file does not exist` error. Full stack trace 

`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/config/incluster_config.py", line 64, in _load_config
    raise ConfigException("Service token file does not exists.")
kubernetes.config.config_exception.ConfigException: Service token file does not exists.`  

Did you faced similar issue with Airflow 1.10.3 ? In my case, Airflow is running on GKE with workload identity enabled.

Comment: @pradeep how did you end up fixing the error `Service token file does not exist`?

Comment: @pradeep/ @AnumSheraz I am having the same error -?  `Service token file does not exist`. Any help on this ?

Comment: I am getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/airflow/report_configs'` even after having different volumes for the KubernetesPodOperator. I believe the `volumes` and `volumeMounts` are the `list` type and would add all volumes (each one with different pvc/pv). This works for other opreators such as Bash and Python but not for KubernetesPodOperator. Anyone having same issue ??

Comment: In case anyone is still running into `Service token file does not exist` using GKE Workload Identity and the Kubernetes Executor with in_cluster = True, make sure you have both the `serviceAccountName` specified in the deployment yaml, and that `automountServiceAccountToken` is True. According to the docs that last one should default to True, but I didn't see the token volume appear until I set it explicitly. After setting those, everything behaved as expected.

Comment: @brandondtb your response may not be the answer to the OP's question... But thanks!!! Never heard of automountServiceAccountToken, but solved my problem!